# Access VCL from other thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, vcl

I wrote a communication class based on TThread, which would send some data and receive a reply. 
I want the method to:

1. sent the data (this is a non blocking procedure)
2. wait for a reply or timeout
3. show the data received in a vcl control
4. give back control to the caller

Here is how I try to do,

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 1 to 5 do // send 5 commands
    mycomm.SendCommand();
end;

procedure TMyComm.ShowData();
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Frame received');
end;

procedure TMyComm.SendCommand();
begin
    //build frame and put it on interface here
    //...

    event.WaitFor(3000);

    //show received frame if no timeout in VCL
    //...
end;

procedure TMyComm.Execute();
begin
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if receive() then //blocks until frame is received
      begin
        Synchronize(ShowData); //hangs :-(
        event.SetEvent;
      end;
    end,
end;
```

Of course this will result in a deadlock, but how can I achieve that my VCL is updated immediately after each received frame?

Comment: Why bother using a thread at all here?  You're blocking the main thread waiting for the worker thread to finish its work... so what's the point?

Comment: Don't wait for the reply in the main thread. Send the commands and then move on. Let the thread notify the main thread whenever a reply arrives.

Comment: Knowing the Delphi version would be nice.

Comment: I need a thread because receive() could block forever when no reply is received. When I don't wait for the reply I can not simply call commands consecutively. I'm using Delphi XE8.

Comment: You did not provide full code so it is not possible to answer. But you definitely do not use thread correctly. You are supposed to do both SendCommand() and receive() inside a thread (depending on your situation it can be 1 thread or 2 threads) and just send result to VCL using synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a anonymous thread, this will only execute the rest of the code after the thread has finished, change it to suite your needs.
You can find the AnonThread Unit in :

*C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\Delphi\RTL\CrossPlatform Utils*

```
uses
 AnonThread 

var
    GetFrame :TAnonymousThread<Boolean>;

begin
    GetFrame := TAnonymousThread<Boolean>.Create(function : Boolean
    begin
    // Start your execution      
    end,
    procedure (AResult : Boolean)
    begin
    // Wil only execute after the thread has run its course, also safe to do UI updates       
    end,
    procedure (AException : Exception)
    begin
        ShowMessage('Error : ' + AException.Message);
    end);
```